# Is there a way to add variable txt to ppt using python?

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

For example, I am creating ppt using a fixed template, and that template has a fixed text on the first slide.
I want to be able to add variable text in the title itself basis on certain conditions.

example:
my title page says "Total trades in Asia"
I want the other country ppt's to read "Total trades in Asia- China"
"Total trades in Asia- India"
"Total trades in Asia- *****" ------> The last text should change acc to the condition

Can anyone help achieve this?

Comment: The pptx library allows you to create and edit power points. check out the shapes.title.text property of a slide: 
slide.shapes.title.text = title

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.